# How to create a service application for Gear S?

Tags: tizen, background-service, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app, service-application

Has anyone succeeded in creating a service application as described in [Service Application: Creating a Service Application](https://developer.tizen.org/documentation/tutorials/web-application/tizen-features/service-application) with Tizen SDK for Wearable 1.0.0?

I followed the the instructions as described in the link above: installed the partner level certification, wrote the `config.xml` as in the example. However, the service doesn't want to start.

I thought maybe this type of application is not supported in Tizen SDK for Wearable 1.0.0 and I started using the Tizen IDE 2.3, but again no success.

I would like to create an app that collects some data from different sensors such as UV or light, and if the values rich a certain threshold I would like to open the main app (with UI) and notify the user of what has happened.

I have already tried using Alarm Manager, with a specific recurrence, but this opens the UI also and is a bit frustrating for the user to have his watch opening and closing the same app repeatedly.

For reference, I am deploying the app on a real device - Gear S (does the device need an update?).

If you have any suggestions about this or any ways to build a background service that doesn't require a UI, I would appreciate any of them.

Answer (score 1):

Tizen 2.3 is not on any shipping wearable device, so you should be using the 1.0 Wearable SDK for Gear S. The Tizen profile for Wearable was split from the main platform for Gear 2 and Gear S and it was merged for the 2.3 release. I don't know if Tizen 2.3 will end up on Gear S or not. [Here is the link](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.native.appprogramming/html/guide/app/service_app_fundamentals.htm) for the version of Tizen that is on the Gear S.